# Address that can pay "commission"?

Tags: wallet, multi-signature

There is a use case where person A needs to send person B, .9 BTC.  Person C, who set up the transaction, should get .1 BTC as commission.

I know this is possible to do with a traditional "bitcoin wallet" by creating a transaction with two payees.  The problem is that for usability reasons, the payment needs to be "[bip-21](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki)" compatible, which basically means it has to be of the form `bitcoin:<address>[?amount=<amount>][?label=<label>][?message=<message>]` which only allows for one output address.

So my question is, is there a way to make some "intermediary" address that will forward .9 to A and .1 to C?  Or is there some other way to do this within the constraints of bip-21?

Comment: yes.  i'm wondering if there is a way to hack it by doing something with an address that i setup instead of relying on the client wallet?

Comment: Deleting my comment because it's not true. Maybe I tested with mainnet address in Bitcoin Core(testnet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

The Bitcoin protocol (currently) has no affordances to control what a recipient can do with coins they receive.